# The solution of APUE exercises 3.4

Tags: c, unix

```
dup2(fd, 0);
dup2(fd, 1);
dup2(fd, 2);
if(fd > 2)
   close(fd);
```

I don't understand why close fd when fd > 2.

I know that 0, 1, 2 and 3 are associated with the same file table entry when fd = 3, but why does fd need to be closed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain clearly what exactly it is you are asking.  There is no context as to what APUE is as well as the question you're trying to answer.  What is ```dup2```?

Comment: APUE is probably a [SIA](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=self%20invented%20acronym). For the book *[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment)*.

Comment: Source code [is available](http://www.apuebook.com/code3e.html): *"The source code for the examples in the book is available for download here as a gzipped tar archive."*

Answer (score 1):

The three [`dup2()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) calls associate the open file description (see [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)) for `fd` with file descriptors 0 (standard input), 1 (standard output) and 2 (standard error).  If `fd` happens to have the value 0, 1 or 2, no harm is done; `dup2(n, n)` is a no-op for any value of `n`.

But if `fd` was greater than 2, that would give the process an extra file descriptor that's open, but the intent is to set up only the three primary file descriptors.  Hence the `close(fd)` ensures that the process only has the three primary file descriptors open (as a result of this code — if there was another file descriptor open before this code was executed, it stays open).